# DokuWiki on Windows wont send email

Tags: php, email, sendmail, dokuwiki

I set up DokuWiki on a Windows 2012 Server using [wampserver](http://www.wampserver.com/)

It works really well, but I can't get it to see any smtp server. I set up a local server using IIS, tested it using blat. I added the following lines to the php.ini:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from address@host.com
```

I also tried using the computer's domain as the server, but Doku won't send any email. Looking at Doku's wiki, I found these helpful instructions: [dokuwiki email](https://www.dokuwiki.org/tips:mailconfig), but I always get an error that says "Looks like there was an error on sending the password mail. Please contact the admin!"

I also tried the 'fake sendmail', but it gave me the same result.

I reset Apache and IIS after changing the configs, but there was no change. There is nothing in the log files either.

As far as I can tell, this should work. Is there another config file or something else that I missed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just pointing PHP to localhost for a mail server won't work unless you run a mailserver there.

You have three options:

1. configure your php.ini to point to a mail server on your LAN
2. run a local Mailserver (eg. http://www.pendriveapps.com/portable-smtp-server-mini-relay/)
3. use the swiftmail plugin (https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:swiftmail) to configure DokuWiki to use some other external mailserver (eg. gMail).

Comment: Sorry, I thought i mentioned that in the original post. I installed smtp on the localhost. I can send email from it with another program, setting the smtp server to 'localhost'. So it **seems** like the smtp part is square.

Comment: No logs. Which lead me to think that the issue was with the php config. Well, turns out I had a conflicting PHP install on the PATH. I changed the SMTP variables in that php.ini and things started working.  Thanks for the help!!